# What happens when you create a file, write to it and then read it?

Tags: posix

Here's the scenario:

- open a new file for write (ie create)
- preform multiple writes
- open the same file for read (using the filename)
- read using the second file handle

So the file has been created and written to, but not flushed or closed.

For POSIX / Linux...

I assume that the handle returned by the second open can be used to read the content that was written to the first open handle. Is that so?

Does the second open also cause a flush?

Comment: Unless you've opened without `O_DSYNC`, writes won't go to disk right away (assuming a regular file) but that doesn't matter. On the second open, the kernel will serve you what it's got in cache. No kernel flush required. All this assumes your using raw syscalls without userspace buffering (=no stdio).

Comment: If you open a file with write permissions, "w", perform the write, then why do you need to read the file? Didn't you just tell the program what you wanted inside the file? (so don't you already know what's in it?)

Comment: PSkocik - thanks. elbrant - the second open can be from a different process, which doesn't know what has been written.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found what should happen according to the "semantics of POSIX I/O" and that is that after every write the data is guaranteed to have been committed, and that therefore any subsequent open/read will see the data of all preceding writes.

Here's a comment on the specification:

> "That is, writes must be strongly consistent–that is, a write() is required to block application execution until the system can guarantee that any other read() call will see the data that was just written" (ref: https://www.nextplatform.com/2017/09/11/whats-bad-posix-io/)

This begs the question, what is the purpose of flush() if every write commits the data before returning? I see that this appears to be a misunderstanding on my part - since POSIX has fflush() (not flush) and fflush() applies to streams not files.

FYI my confusion arose because I was assuming FUSE operators map to POSIX file operations, and FUSE does have a flush operator. So I guess FUSE is not necessarily POSIX compliant wrt write()? This makes sense to allow for some FUSE implementations to return before data is committed where not doing so is impractical (eg for performance reasons). I'm speculating there, so any comments on this would be appreciated.

Comment: “this begs the questions” does not mean “this raises the question”. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question

Answer (score 2):

First question is answered from the POSIX manual :

> After a `write()` to a regular file has successfully returned:
>
> Any successful `read()` from each byte position in the file that was
> modified by that write shall return the data specified by the `write()`
> for that position until such byte positions are again modified.

For the second question, there is no need for flush... Everything that was written is in the hands of the kernel, so any read can have access to it if required by the standard. Flush is usually meant for pushing data from user space buffer to kernel space (or something in the hands of). Now, if you mean flushed to disk, there is usually no requirement for this... If needed look at Direct IOs.